# Specifying rails version to use when creating a new application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two versions of rails (2.1.0 and 2.2.2) installed in my computer.

When I create a  new application, is it possible to specify that I want to use the older (2.1.0) version?

Comment: http://www.railshorde.com/blog/rails-command-to-create-new-application-with-specific-version-and-database

Answer (score 536, accepted):

I found [here](http://craiccomputing.blogspot.com/2008/06/using-older-versions-of-rails.html) an undocumented option to create a new application using an older version of Rails.

```
rails _2.1.0_ new myapp
```

Comment: You should change this to the accepted answer since it works for Rails 2 and 3. Keltia's answer will no longer work if you have Rails 3 installed and want a Rails 2 app.

Comment: Erroneous that having Rails 3 installed fails for _2.3.5_ -- Just tested on Mac OS X Snow Leopard with these modules installed:rails (3.0.5, 2.3.5, 2.2.2, 1.2.6)

Comment: This is RubyGems functionality, not Rails functionality; it's therefore not dependent on Rails version, and will work for other gems. (Thanks, this is a great answer!)

Comment: I get error when using 3.1.3 when 3.1.3 and 3.2.0.rc1 are installed. Here is the error ---

[ninad@localhost devel]$ rails `_3.1.3_` new sample_app
/home/ninad/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:314:in `bin_path': can't find gem railties (["3.1.3"]) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
 from /home/ninad/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'

Comment: Very helpful now that 4.0.0 is out!

Comment: This also works for engines: `rails _3.2.11_ plugin new myapp`

Comment: Doesn't work with `ruby` => `2.3.2`, < `2.4`.
The bug was introduced in a
[backport](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/996b1bfa95)
solving another
[issue](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12326).
It appeared in `2.4` branch and was fixed before any kind of release.

In terms of `rubygems`
that would be >= [`2.5.2`](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/pull/1407),
< [`2.6.2`](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/pull/1527).
The workaround is update `rubygems`
and then binstubs:
`gem update --system && gem pristine --all --only-executables`.

Answer (score 77):

Here is the command which I use normally:

```
rails _version_ new application_name
```

for example `rails _7.0.4_ new my_app`

Here is the list of all available rails versions so far:

http://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions

Answer (score 29):

I was having some trouble using `rails _version_ new application_name` (the resulting project was still generated for the newest version of Rails installed.)

After a bit of digging I found [an article](https://relativkreativ.at/articles/how-to-manage-multiple-rails-versions) by [Michael Trojanek](https://relativkreativ.at/about) with an alternative approach. This works by creating a folder with a Gemfile specifying the desired version of Rails and then using `bundle exec rails...` so that Bundler takes care of running  the appropriate version of `rails`. e.g. to make a new Rails 4.2.9 projects the steps are:

```
mkdir myapp
cd myapp
echo "source 'https://rubygems.org'" > Gemfile
echo "gem 'rails', '4.2.9'" >> Gemfile
bundle install

bundle exec rails new . --force --skip-bundle
bundle update
```

Comment: I don't think there is need of `bundle update`, it will update rails too!!

Comment: @devel the `bundle update` is needed because a manual update is being used (`--skip-bundle`). Rails won't be upgraded because a specific version is specified in the Gemfile (4.2.9 in the example.)

Comment: `--force` is overwriting the Gemfile

Comment: Yep, but the new Gemfile that gets written _still_ specifies the version of Rails we wanted (because `bundle exec rails new...` ran the version of `rails` specified in the Gemfile that ends up being replaced.)

Comment: I did `gem 'rails', '5.0.0.1' >> Gemfile` and after running `bundle exec rails new` with --force option, its `gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'` in Gemfile. Now when I run `bundle update`, its updating the rails to 5.0.4 (in Gemfile.lock), but I was expecting to use rails version 5.0.0.1

Comment: @devel thanks for sticking with this! It looks like a difference between 4.x and 5.x versions. I hadn't spotted this as I've mostly used this approach for creating 4.x apps since the release of Rails 5. With 5.0.1 the generated Gemfile specifies the version using the [~>](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#pessimistic-version-constraint) operator: `gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'`. So you might need to edit the Gemfile after the `bundle exec rails new...` if you want to stick on the exact version.

Answer (score 18):

As rightly pointed out by @mikej for **Rails 5.0.0 or above**, you should be following these steps:

Create a directory for your application along with a Gemfile to specify your desired Rails version and let bundler install the dependent gems:

```
$ mkdir myapp
$ cd myapp
$ echo "source 'https://rubygems.org'" > Gemfile
$ echo "gem 'rails', '5.0.0.1'" >> Gemfile
$ bundle install
```

Check that the correct version of rails has been installed: `$ bundle exec rails -v`

Now create your application, let Rails create a new Gemfile (or rather overwrite the existing one by using the `--force` flag) and instead of installing the bundle (`--skip-bundle`) update it manually:

```
$ bundle exec rails new . --force --skip-bundle
```

If you check the entry for rails in `Gemfile`, it should be like this:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
```

You should update it to the exact version needed for the application:

```
gem 'rails', '5.0.0.1'
```

Now, the final step:

```
$ bundle update
```

Answer (score 10):

There are two ways to achieve this:

one as suggested in accepted answer:

```
gem install rails -v 2.1.0 #only when the gem has not been installed in the desired ruby version you are using, so that you don't get error on next step
rails _2.1.0_ new my_app
```

and alternative method is to create gemfile with desired rails version before initializing rails project

```
mkdir my_app
cd my_app
echo "source 'https://rubygems.org'" > Gemfile
echo "gem 'rails', '2.1.0'" >> Gemfile
bundle install

bundle exec rails new . --force --skip-bundle
```

I have written about this in details in my [article](https://www.sharmaprakash.com.np/rails/generate-an-application-with-a-specific-rails-version/)

Answer (score 3):

You can generate the skeleton with either version and require the one you want in `config/environment.rb`:

```
# Specifies gem version of Rails to use when vendor/rails is not present
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.1.2' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

or use the "rails" command form the version you want anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You should also take a look at "freezing" your Rails gems into the app. This helps a lot with deployment, specially in shared hosting environments.

Just change the `RAILS_GEM_VERSION` variable in `config/environment.rb` and issue the freeze rake task:

```
rake rails:freeze:gems
```

Comment: use rvm use rubyversion

Answer (score 0):

Please watch out which version of ruby you are using with Rails.

The command for making a new project for a specific version of Rail may not work for you. I had some issues about it. And the problem was the ruby version I have default which is 3.0.0. This version did not work with Rails 5. Then I installed ruby 2.7.5 and switched to it as default. Only then I was able to make projects both for Rails 5 and 7.

If you want the same environment with ruby 2.7.5

```
rvm install ruby-2.7.5
```

switch to this version as default

```
rvm --default use 2.7.5
```

install bundler and webpacker

```
gem install bundler
gem install webpacker
```

install lastest rails (which is 7)

```
gem install rails
```

test it

```
rails new test_app_6
cd test_app_6
rails s
```

check for localhost 3000

```
http://localhost:3000
```

then stop the server (control + c) and install Rails 5

```
gem install rails -v 5.2.6
```

test it

```
rails _5.2.6_ new test_app_5
cd test_app_5
rails s
```

check for localhost 3000

```
http://localhost:3000
```

You're set!