# "rails new project_name" for 3.0 and 3.1 using rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to create rails 3.0 and rails 3.1 projects with rbenv? I know that with rvm I can create new gemsets and switch to them to create a 3.0 or 3.1 project. However, gemsets to not exist with rbenv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is this
[Specifying rails version to use when creating a new application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379141/specifying-rails-version-to-use-when-creating-a-new-application)

You can create different version of rails projects by passing in the appropriate parameters to the `rails` command

Answer (score 0):

The gemset solution for rbenv requires an additional plugin. From the [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) page:

> In contrast with rvm, rbenv does not… Manage gemsets. Bundler is a better way to manage application dependencies. If you have projects that are not yet using Bundler you can install the [rbenv-gemset](https://github.com/jamis/rbenv-gemset) plugin.

It isn't quite as cut and dry as the rvm solution, but once you've got it set up, it should work just fine for you.

I'd highly recommend you check out the documentation on the [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) page - it'll give you more info on building rubies, etc.

### Update

I've realized that you're probably asking about project specific gemsets, but creating it before. You'll probably want to create a global gemset that has bundler and rails in it, run `rails new project_name`, then add the `.rbenv-gemsets` file to the project.