# Create a new project in rails older version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version, project, new-operator

I have rails version 3.2.1 in my machine. The other versions installed are 3.0, 3.0.3. Whenever i run

```
 rails new PROJECT_NAME
```

command ,the project gets created in version 3.2.1. I want to create the project in version 3.0.3.

What should i do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specifying rails version to use when creating a new application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379141/specifying-rails-version-to-use-when-creating-a-new-application)

Comment: The question is for Rails 2.x but the answer still works form Rails 3.X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggest using bundler.  Your project will have a Gemfile in which you specify the rails version you want:

gem "rails", "~> 3.0.3"

Once you have installed the bundler gem, `bundle install` will install the version of Rails you have specified.

Then, when you are ready to upgrade your version of Rails, you do this by specifying the version number you want to move to.  Of course, this approach helps manage all of the gems that your project depends on, including the ones you only want in test and dev etc.

See http://gembundler.com/ for more.

Answer (score 32):

you can create new app with older version

```
rails _3.0.3_ new appname
```

but you may get error as

`/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:316:in`bin_path': can't find gem `railties (["3.0.3"]) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
from /usr/local/bin/rails:19:in`'

so

again install rails gem

```
sudo gem install rails -v="3.0.3"
```

now you can do

```
rails _3.0.3_ new app
```

it will work fine

thank you

Comment: I think that `sudo gem install rails -v="3.0.3"` should be `sudo gem install rails -v "3.0.3"`

Comment: Hi Tass,

we can use both. Both will work, i just tried out and its worked.

Comment: Weird. I tried that first syntax yesterday and it didn't work for me. >.< Perhaps I should look into it again and see what kind of errors (if any) I receive.

Comment: Best thing is use RVM and install gems without sudo.

Comment: I completely agree, but this is a production FreeBSD server which doesn't have RVM set up. In development I do use RVM.

Comment: can I somehow setup an app with the latest version of a major version, i.e. something like `rails _6_ new appname` but that resolves to 6.1.5 rather than 6.0.0?

Answer (score 12):

You could use something like RVM and install the other rails versions in a different gemset. Then select the gemset with an older rails version and your rails command should be from the older version.

Alternatively you should be able to use

```
rails _VERSION_ new myapp
```

Comment: Just to clarify that the underscores are not emphasis.  This is the actual syntax required.  E.g. `rails _2.3.14_ new myapp`.

Comment: anyone know a way to set this as a default?