# Creating a new rails app in 3.0.10 while I have 3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to create a new rails app in 3.0.10 but the latest rails in my machine is 3.1.3. If I run:

```
gem list rails
```

Then I get the following output:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (3.1.3, 3.0.11, 3.0.10, 3.0.9, 3.0.7, 3.0.6, 3.0.4.rc1)
rails3-jquery-autocomplete (1.0.5)
```

Now I have applications in both 3.1 and 3.0 so I don't want to remove 3.1. How can I create this new rails app in 3.0.10?

Comment: Hi visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379141/specifying-rails-version-to-use-when-creating-a-new-application

Comment: @soundar looks like that worked. Put the same comment in the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: You can vote in the comment itself if you wish :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To create a rails application for a specific version you can use this syntax:
`$rails _3.0.10_ new appname`

**NOTE**: The underscores are needed.

Comment: For a moment I thought the underscores were used as emphasis, but they're actually part of this undocumented syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely use RVM (ruby version manager), to use different versions of rails can be reached easily:

```
rvm gemset create rails3
rvm gemset create rails3.2
rvm gemset create rails3.1
```

then, to you should use on of them to create rails project

```
rvm gemset use rails3 && gem install rails -v 3.0.10
rvm gemset use rails3.2 && gem install rails -v 3.2.2
rvm gemset use rails3.1 && gem install rails -v 3.1
```