# Can you run a rails console or rake command in the elastic beanstalk environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have set up a RoR environement on AWS' elastic beanstalk.  I am able to ssh into my EC2 instance.
My home directory is /**home/ec2-user**, which is effectively empty.
If I move up a directory, there is also a **/home/webapp** directory that i do not have access to.

Is there a way to run a **rake** command or **rails console** on my elastic beanstalk instance?

If I type **rails console** I get `Usage: rails new APP_PATH [options]`
If I type **RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console**, I get "`Could not locate Gemfile`"

Comment: finally... I found the solution. look at this https://gist.github.com/tarom/e99fa97c3916c6717baa it worked for me.

Comment: Amazon Linux 2 solution that works in 2023 and beyond: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75065608/545137

Answer (score 60, accepted):

For rails, jump to `/var/app/current` then as @juanpastas said, run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c`

Comment: `cd $EB_CONFIG_APP_CURRENT` goes to /var/app/current. `sudo RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c` gives `bundler: command not found: rails`. If I specify the path to rails, `sudo RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec /usr/local/bin/rails c`, I get `Could not find addressable-2.3.6 in any of the sources`. There is something strange going on with how Beanstalk and/or Passenger bundles gems, maybe related to the shared gems described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13657473/550712).

Comment: see my answer: it should solve all problems: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60585463/3090068

Answer (score 45):

Don't know why, but since EBS runs everything as root, this worked for me:

```
sudo su
bundle exec rails c production
```

Comment: Yep, this worked for me too.  ```cd /var/app current; sudo su; bundle exec rails c ```  Not sure why but production at the end wasn't needed.

Comment: This actually runs your rails in `root` user; but current Elastic Beanstalk platform assumes you run rails application in `webapp` user.  So, I'd argue we should use `webapp` for what ever command we are using, and doing so is explained in my answer see my answer: it should solve all problems: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60585463/3090068

Comment: `sudo su` uses 2 commands. You can just use `sudo -i`that runs login shell.

Answer (score 14):

None of these solutions mentioned here worked for me, so I cooked up a little script that I put in script/aws-console.

You can run it from the /var/app/current directory as root:

```
eb ssh
cd /var/app/current
sudo script/aws-console
```

My script can be found as a [Gist here](https://gist.github.com/wearethefoos/7348931fbcdb3bb1a21d).

Answer (score 9):

None of the other answers worked for me so I went looking - this is working for me now on an elastic beanstalk 64bit amazon linux 2016.03 V2.1.2 ruby 2.2 (puma) stack

```
cd /var/app/current
sudo su
rake rails:update:bin
bundle exec rails console
```

that returns me the expected console

```
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.6)
irb(main):001:0>
```

Comment: Where are you typing `cd/var/app/current`? Is it on your local machine? It says `-bash: cd: /var/app/current: No such file or directory` for me.

Comment: @KaMok - nah, you need to open an ssh connection to your EB instance - something like `eb ssh myinstancename` - type 'yes' for the auth key and then you'll get dumped to a console where you can type the above.

Comment: You don't need `myinstancename` if you're `cd` into the directory.

Answer (score 8):

For Ruby 2.7:

if you don't need environment variables:

```sh
BUNDLE_PATH=/var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ bundle exec rails c
```

It looks like environment variables are not loaded automatically anymore, which might prevent rails console from starting.
I solved it by creating this .ebextensions file:

```yaml
# Simply call `sudo /var/app/scripts/rails_c`

commands:
  create_script_dir:
    command: "mkdir -p /var/app/scripts"
    ignoreErrors: true
files:
  "/var/app/scripts/export_envvars":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/shims/ruby

      if __FILE__ == $0
          require 'json'
          env_file = '/var/app/scripts/envvars'
          env_vars = env_vars = JSON.parse(`/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment`)

          str = ''
          env_vars.each do |key, value|
              new_key = key.gsub(/\s/, '_')
              str << "export #{new_key}=\"#{value}\"\n"
          end

          File.open(env_file, 'w') { |f| f.write(str) }
      end
  "/var/app/scripts/rails_c":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      . ~/.bashrc
      /var/app/scripts/export_envvars
      . /var/app/scripts/envvars
      cd /var/app/current
      /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec rails c
```

Comment: For those using dotenv, this is simpler: 
`sudo cp -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env /var/app/current/.env`

`cd /var/app/current && rails console`

Answer (score 6):

Create a .ebextension file named **setvars.config** and add those lines to it

```
commands:
  setvars:
    command: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | "export \(.key)=\"\(.value)\""' > /etc/profile.d/sh.local
packages:
  yum:
    jq: []
```

Then deploy your code again it should work.
reference: https://aws.amazon.com/ar/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-env-variables-shell/

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me with a Rails 7 app on Elastic Beanstalk

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/sh

shell_join () {
  ruby -r shellwords -e 'puts Shellwords.join(ARGV)' "$@"
}


command_str () {
  printf 'set -e; . /etc/profile.d/eb_envvars.sh; . /etc/profile.d/use-app-ruby.sh; set -x; exec %s\n' "$(shell_join "$@")"
}

exec sudo su webapp -c "$(command_str "$@")"
```

Put above file somewhere in your source code, deploy, `eb ssh` into the eb instance, `cd /var/app/current`, and then execute `path/to/above/script bin/rails whatever argumeents you usually use`.

Reason why I have written above script is:

1. When using `sudo`, it drops some environment variables which might actually be needed for your rails app; so manually load the profiles which the Elastic Beanstalk platform provides.
2. Current Beanstalk ruby platform assumes you run rails application on user `webapp`, a non-login-able user, so it would be wise to run your command in this user.

Comment: How do I use this to run my rake tasks as webapp? As it is, it seems to run as root.

Comment: @ptoinson I forgot to add to specify the user for `su` command..  Just edited and added `webapp` to `su` argument.

Comment: > /etc/profile.d/eb_envvars.sh: No such file or directory
Do you have an updated version ? maybe based on /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env  ?

Comment: This answer was written in 2020. I think Elastic Beanstalk (platform) has been updated and maybe this answer is no longer valid.

Comment: I think, too hence my question :) I was hoping that maybe you , as the author, had an updated script somewhere

Comment: Sorry, currently I don't work on projects which use Elastic Beanstalk; so, no, I don't have updated script.

Answer (score 3):

For Ruby 2.7:

As someone said, if you don't need env vars, run the following

```sh
BUNDLE_PATH=/var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ bundle exec rails c
```

However, if you need ENV, I recommend doing this as per AWS doc:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-env-variables-linux2/

tl;dr

On Amazon Linux 2, all environment properties are centralised into a single file called `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env`. No user can access these outside the app. So, they recommend to add some hook scripts after deploy to basically create a copy.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#Create a copy of the environment variable file.
cp /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/custom_env_var

#Set permissions to the custom_env_var file so this file can be accessed by any user on the instance. You can restrict permissions as per your requirements.
chmod 644 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/custom_env_var

#Remove duplicate files upon deployment.
rm -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/*.bak
```

If because of some reason you don't want to run as root, do the following to pass env vars from root into new user environment:

```sh
sudo -u <user> -E env "PATH=$PATH" bash -c 'cd /var/app/current/ && <wtv you want to run>'
```

Comment: For those using dotenv, this is simpler: 
`sudo cp -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env /var/app/current/.env`

`cd /var/app/current && rails console`

Answer (score 2):

I like to create an `eb_console` file at the root of my rails app, then `chmod u+x` it. It contains the following:

```
ssh -t ec2-user@YOUR_EC2_STATION.compute.amazonaws.com  'cd /var/app/current && bin/rails c'
```

This way, I just have to run:

```
./eb_console
```

like I would have run `heroku run bundle exec rails c`.

Answer (score 1):

For the latest ruby version, please use the following command:

> BUNDLE_PATH=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/ bundle exec rails c production

Running it with sudo is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

add an eb extension shortcut:

```
# .ebextensions/irb.config
files:
  "/home/ec2-user/irb":
    mode: "000777"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      sudo su - -c 'cd /var/app/current; bundle exec rails c'
```

then:

```
$ eb ssh
$ ./irb
irb(main):001:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a **new** reason this won't work with the latest Amazon Linux 2023, with Architecture of arm64. You can get this error when running `bin/rails c`:

```
> bin/rails c
/var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require': cannot load such file -- irb (LoadError)
Did you mean?  erb
               drb
    from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:3:in `<main>'
    from <internal:/usr/share/ruby3.2-rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from <internal:/usr/share/ruby3.2-rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in lookup'
    from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:40:in `each'
    from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:40:in `block in lookup'
    from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:39:in `each'
    from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:39:in `lookup'
    from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command.rb:73:in `find_by_namespace'
    from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from <internal:/usr/share/ruby3.2-rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from <internal:/usr/share/ruby3.2-rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /var/app/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.7/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

It appears that Amazon doesn't ship the `irb` gem by default like it used to.

The solution is simple though. You just need to **explicitly** add the irb gem to your Gemfile and then re-deploy.

Specifically, add:

```rb
gem "irb"
```

to your `Gemfile`, and the redeploy your app!

Answer (score -1):

None of these were working for me, including the aws-console script. I finally ended up creating a `script` directory in `/var/app/current` and then creating a `rails` file in that directory as outline by [this answer on another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17647039).

```
eb ssh myEnv
cd /var/app/current
sudo mkdir script
sudo vim script/rails
```

Add this to file and save:

```
echo #!/usr/bin/env ruby
# This command will automatically be run when you run "rails" with Rails 3 gems installed from the root of your application.

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
require 'rails/commands'
```

Then make it executable and run it:

```
sudo chmod +x script/rails
sudo script/rails console
```

And it worked.

Answer (score -2):

You have to find the folder with your Gemfile :p.

To do that, I would take a look in you web server config there should be a config that tells you where your app directory is.

Maybe you know where your app is.

But in case you don't know, I would give a try to:

```
grep -i your_app_name /etc/apache/*
grep -i your_app_name /etc/apache/sites-enabled/*
```

To search files containing your_app_name in Apache config.

Or if you are using nginx, replace `apache` above by `nginx`.

after you find application folder, cd into it and run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c`.

Making sure that your application is configured to run in production in Apache or nginx configuration.

Comment: There is no directory /etc/apache or /etc/nginx. As far as I can tell, elastic beanstalk uses passenger.  And there was no /etc/passenger directory either.

Comment: usually, I use passenger on top of nginx or Apache... so Apache or nginx should be there... weird...

Comment: In Beanstalk, the gemfile is in `/var/app/current`. The `$EB_CONFIG_APP_CURRENT` environment variable points there.