# How does one run rails console in an Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How does one run `rails console` in an Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance? I've tried to SSH into the EC2 instance, but dont see any indication of the project directories listed anywhere.

Additionally, I'd also like to manually run commands like `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=1234 --trace`.

Comment: This link should help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620897/can-you-run-a-rails-console-or-rake-command-in-the-elastic-beanstalk-environment

Comment: Good stuff, why doesn't `ls -a` in the EC2 tunnel show a `/var` directory though..