# Run Rails rake task in Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, rake, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Does anyone know the easiest way to run a rake task for a Rails app on an Elastic Beanstalk environment?

I have some data that I want to reset every once in a while (timeline TBD).  I've seen other posts talking about creating a cron task, but I just want to be able to execute the task on a one-off basis for now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you run a rails console or rake command in the elastic beanstalk environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620897/can-you-run-a-rails-console-or-rake-command-in-the-elastic-beanstalk-environment)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd need to login to the box in order to run a rake task.
simply run `eb ssh <env-name>`
your app is at `/var/app/current`

Comment: oh - just saw you found an answer. I think "eb ssh" would serve you better than plain ssh.

Comment: Yea, thanks for the tip on the "eb ssh."  One thing I had to do was create a "known_hosts" folder in my .ssh directory and move a copy of my .pem key there to get it to work

Answer (score 2):

For Amazon Linux 2 you need to export your Elastic Beanstalk variables to the shell profile so that they can be used to invoke your `rails` command from inside the `/var/app/current` directory.

This approach might look scary to some of you, but it's really nothing special. Basically the root-protected `/etc/profile.d/sh.local` file will contain all of your Elastic Beanstalk environment's variables. This includes passwords and master keys ... lots of sensitive stuff. If a bad guy (or girl or bot) compromises your app by somehow ssh'ing into your Elastic Beanstalk instance, **they WILL be able mess with your app**. If that terrifies you, stop reading. If you still want to run your rails tasks or console from inside your Elastic Beanstalk instance, read on ...

---

The modern Amazon Linux 2 way to accomplish this is to create a *prebuild hook* file that will write all the Elastic Beanstalk environment variables to `/etc/profile.d/sh.local`. This way when you `eb ssh <YOUR-ENVIRONMENT-NAME>` into your Elastic Beanstalk instance, all of the Elastic Beanstalk variables will be included in YOUR shell session.

In your Rails app, create a new script file precisely at: `<YOUR_RAILS_APP_ROOT>/.platform/hooks/prebuild/set-vars.sh`. The file's will be:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# put envars into /etc/profile.d/sh.local so that they an be used to `bundle exec rails c`
# see https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-env-variables-shell/

# installs `jq` to transform the json representation of the env vars
# into shell-happy looking env-vars
yum install -y jq

# write your eb environment variables to /etc/profile.d/sh.local
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | "export \(.key)=\"\(.value)\""' > /etc/profile.d/sh.local
```

**Commit this file to your project and deploy your application to Elastic Beanstalk.**

Once the deployment has successfully concluded, ssh into your Elastic Beanstalk instance and try to run some rails commands from your application directory:

```bash
$ eb ssh <YOUR-ENVIRONMENT-NAME>

 _____ _           _   _      ____                       _        _ _
| ____| | __   ___| |_(_) ___| __ )  ___  __ _ _ __  ___| |_ __ _| | | __
|  _| | |/ _ \/ __| __| |/ __|  _ \ / _ \/ _\ | '_ \/ __| __/ _\ | | |/ /
| |___| | (_| \__ \ |_| | (__| |_) |  __/ (_| | | | \__ \ || (_| | |   <
|_____|_|\__,_|___/\__|_|\___|____/ \___|\__,_|_| |_|___/\__\__,_|_|_|\_\

Amazon Linux 2 AMI
```

```bash
$ cd /var/app/current

$ bundle exec rails --version
Rails 7.#.#

$ bundle exec rails -T
rails about                                                   # List versions of all Rails frameworks and the environment
...

$ bundle exec rails c
Loading ... environment (Rails 7.#.#)
irb(main):001:0>
```

Inspiration came from: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-env-variables-shell/

Learn extending Linux 2 Elastic Beanstalk docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

...press the up arrow, mark as modern answer/solution so the rest of us can find this...

Comment: Bless you. 

Comment: hi, this solution (or the others in this topic) are not working anymore with AL2023 ruby 3.2 versions

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a way.

- SSH into your EC2 instance using the following instructions:
  [SSH Instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-connect-to-instance-linux.html) (I used option 3)
- Navigate to the /var/app/current directory once you're logged in
- Run your rake task (`rake db:migrate` or whatever task you're trying to run)