How to run rails console on Amazon Linux 2023 Elastic Beanstalk
enter code hereHow can rails console be run on "Ruby 3.2 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2023/4.0.10"?
Using SSM to access the web server.
On Amazon Linux 2, I had a script that exported environment variables and then ran:
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec rails c

but rbenv is not installed on AL2023 and the directory structure is different.
[Update2]: Running bundle exec rails c from /var/app/current/ gives:
Could not find web-console-4.2.1, rack-mini-profiler-2.3.4, listen-3.9.0, spring-4.2.1, capybara-3.40.0, selenium-webdriver-4.23.0, bindex-0.8.1, rb-fsevent-0.11.2, rb-inotify-0.11.1, matrix-0.4.2, regexp_parser-2.9.2, xpath-3.2.0, base64-0.2.0, logger-1.6.0, rexml-3.3.2, websocket-1.2.11, strscan-3.1.0 in locally installed gems

bundle install runs successfully as root (sudo su).
After adding irb to the Gemfile, bundle exec rails c runs but can't connect to the db in the console (cannot connect to database on 120.0..) I think because we're root user not webapp.
[Update 3] Trying to run the console as webbapp user (sudo -s, su webapp) now gives:
/usr/share/ruby3.2/fileutils.rb:406:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /run/user/0/spring-900 (Errno::EACCES)


Have you just tried to run bundle exec rails c in the rails app dir?

It gives "Could not find web-console-4.2.1, rack-mini-profiler-2.3.4, listen-3.9.0, spring-4.2.1,..." So actually no worse off than from within a script

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620897/can-you-run-a-rails-console-or-rake-command-in-the-elastic-beanstalk-environment and https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-env-variables-shell should help

They don't unfortunately. Seems to be a permissions error running as webapp user, and database connection (security group?) issue running as root.
