# How to create a new rails app with a particular version of rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to ruby and to rails.

How do I create a new application directory using rails 3.2.13? Below is the info regarding my rails installation.

```
$ rails --version
Rails 4.0.4
$ gem list rails

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (4.0.4, 3.2.13)
```

Whenever I create a new rails app, the latest rails, 4.0.4, is being used.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379141/specifying-rails-version-to-use-when-creating-a-new-application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this:

```
rails _3.2.13_ new YOUR_APP_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I had tried this before. But was getting an error. After your answer I tried to read through the error and it occured to me that maybe my default version of ruby(2.0.0) was incompatible with rails 3.2.13. So I changed my default ruby to something lower(1.9.3) and tried creating with the above command and it worked.