# How do i create new rails 3 app when i have already have rails 3 and 4 installed in same ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't want to install `rails 3` or whatever, since i already have it somewhere in my computer. And,it runs smoothly in one of my application . There is one thing special with that `app` is in its `Gemfile` file i have

```
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails',  '3.2.11'
```

I tried few things

1. I tried to run it via absolute path but still it doesn't works. might be i have used wrong path. I went to `GEM_HOME` / `bin` directory and then `rails`. It doesn't work. It is picking `rails 4`
2. I went to `app` which is using `rails 3` and did this `rails new ~/some_rails3_app`. Doesn't work. It gives me this error

   > Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first.
   >   Type 'rails' for help.
3. Created `rails 4` app , changed gem version to `3.2.11` , deleted `Gemfile.lock` and did `bundle install` . Doesn't worked , giving some `coffeescript` version conflict error.

In case if that matters, i am using

1. `Mac`
2. `zsh`
3. `rvm`
4. `ruby 1.9.3p484`
5. `Rails 4.0.3`
6. `Rails 3.2.11`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379141/specifying-rails-version-to-use-when-creating-a-new-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
rails _3.2.11_ new appname
```