# How to generate a dummy app inside an already existing rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rails-engines, legacy-code

I came to work for a company recently that has been working on a specific rails project for a while. Dropped in the middle of the development process, I'm beginning to go back and write tests for the existing code as well as the code currently being produced.

Testing the rails 4 app was easy enough, but once I got to testing the engine, I hit a mental block. After doing my due diligence, I found that most people take an approach like this (http://viget.com/extend/rails-engine-testing-with-rspec-capybara-and-factorygirl), but the common thread I saw in all of these responses was that people were building these apps from scratch, and thus had a dummy app generated for them automatically. I don't have the benefit of being able to generate everything from scratch, and have to work with what I was given, so what

I'd like to know is if there's a way to retroactively generate *just* the dummy application. Is there something simple I can type into the console and have it generated for me? Or is there a longer, slightly less pretty route? Or would a different strategy be better altogether?

Comment: you can puts in `spec/dummy` any app, this is just mount point for you engine, just generate `rails new test_app` and copy `test_app` to dummy folder.

Comment: Why do you need the dummy app anyway? can't you test the engine using the main app?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Given that the dummy app is not supposed to be tied to the parent gem except for some vague names, that *may* do it:

```
cd some_path_where_your_engine_IS_NOT
rails plugin new YOUR_ENGINE_NAME --mountable --dummy-path=spec/dummy --skip-test-unit
mv YOUR_ENGINE_NAME/spec/dummy /real/path/to/YOUR_ENGINE_NAME/spec
rm -rf YOUR_ENGINE_NAME  # cleanup useless cruft
```

Also, you may be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379141/specifying-rails-version-to-use-when-creating-a-new-application) to generate the app with the exact same rails version.

Comment: Specify a Rails version using `_VERSION_` as the first option to the `rails` command. For example, to use Rails 5.0.1: `rails _5.0.1_ plugin new YOUR_ENGINE_NAME --mountable --dummy-path=spec/dummy --skip-test-unit`

Answer (score 1):

If the engine is within a parent app delete the engine from your `Gemfile`

Rerun the `rails plugin new ..` command you used to create the rails engine, but with the `--skip` parameter. This will create all the files, including `dummy` that do not exist in your engine, but leave existing files alone.