# Being forced to use Rails 4.1.1 instead of 3.2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I am following along in a Treehouse tutorial where the instructor is using ruby 1.9.3 with rails 3.2.13. I've already tried `gem uninstall rails` and selected 4.1.1 as well as `gem uninstall railties` and selected 4.1.1.

I have even specified in my gemfile to use `gem 'rails', '3.2.13'`

When I run `bundle`, rails auto updates to `4.1.1`. Is there a possible way to set 3.2.13 as default or even possibly force-block rails 4.1.1?

Comment: I have a hard time believing that your Gemfile specifies 3.2.13, but running `bundle` in that directory uses 4.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Specifying rails version to use when creating a new application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379141/specifying-rails-version-to-use-when-creating-a-new-application)

What they tell you to do:

```
rails _2.1.0_ new myapp
```

So change it to fit your situation

```
rails _3.2.13_ new treehouse
```

Comment: Don’t simply link to another question in your answer, instead vote/flag this question as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: I see I can do that now. I thought I had to have much more rep to do that, but oh well.