# Rails Tutorial for Beginners

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using cloud9 IDE and following the rails tutorial for beginners.

Why doesn't `rails_4.2.0_ new hello_app` (as written in the book) work.

The only thing it says on the terminal is `rails rails_4.2.0_ "command not found"`?

However, when typing, `rails new hello_app 4.2.0` it works. When opening the GEMFILE in the text editor I have to adjust default gems to go along with the tutorial.

Is there a different version of rails comes up?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you add a space between *rails* & *_4.2.0_* ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying rails version to use when creating a new application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379141/specifying-rails-version-to-use-when-creating-a-new-application)

Comment: "following the rails tutorial for beginners" is a very vague description.

Answer (score 0):

Type rails -v and find out what version you have. You can also just type rails new hello app and if you have rails 4.2.0 installed then it should use that version of rails. Make sure you run bundle update if you changed your gem file.