# Error when using command "Rails g controller"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Help, I don't understand this rails error.

I use the latest rails according to bundler's bundle install command.

I am using windows 7.

When I ran the command `"rails g controller abc"` it display error messages like this:

```
C:/Users/Owner/ruby_intro/graded-assignments/recipefinder/config/initializers/ne
w_framework_defaults.rb:21:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `halt_callbac
k_chains_on_return_false=' for ActiveSupport:Module (NoMethodError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8
/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8
/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8
/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8
/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8
/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block i
n tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (
2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (
2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_st
rongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block i
n each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_st
rongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block i
n each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_st
rongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_e
ach'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_e
ach'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8
/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Users/Owner/ruby_intro/graded-assignments/recipefinder/config/en
vironment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8
/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8
/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:142:in `require_application_and_environmen
t!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:128:in `generate_or_destroy'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:50:in `generate'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.8
/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Can anybody help?

Thank you and forgive me for the broken English.

Comment: Which rails version do you use?

Comment: [try this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189879/trouble-with-new-rails-app)

Comment: I use rails 4.2.8. when i downgraded it to 4.2.3, i can't use the rails command and it ask for update

Comment: @rarefever, i tried the solution from that post but nothing change. thank you for your tip