# Specify the rails version when creating a new rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following Rails versions installed:

```
➜ gem list --local
[...]
rails (5.0.1, 4.2.7.1, 3.2.22.5)
[...]
```

I want to create an application with rails version `4.2.7.1` and found this topic: [Specifying rails version to use when creating a new application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379141/specifying-rails-version-to-use-when-creating-a-new-application), where the solution is to run

```
rails _4.2.7.1_ new MYAPP
```

Unfortunately this is not working for me, the Gemfile generated by this command still states `gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'`:

```
➜ rails _4.2.7.1_ new MYAPP --skip-bundle
      create
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/javascripts/cable.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
      create  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/jobs/application_job.rb
      create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
      create  app/models/application_record.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/assets/javascripts/channels
      create  app/assets/javascripts/channels/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  bin/update
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/secrets.yml
      create  config/cable.yml
      create  config/puma.rb
      create  config/spring.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/application_controller_renderer.rb
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/cors.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
      create  public/apple-touch-icon.png
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/fixtures/files
      create  test/fixtures/files/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp
      create  tmp/.keep
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
      remove  config/initializers/cors.rb
➜ cd MYAPP
➜ cat Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I use these versions of rbenv and ruby:

```
➜ rbenv -v
rbenv 1.1.0
➜ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

Running `rails -v` returns `Rails 5.0.1`, maybe there's the problem?
Can you please help me?

Comment: have you tried rails _4.2.7._ new MYAPP ?

Comment: I did, and it doesn't seem to work, rails seems to don't know what to do with this command and returns the `rails help` output.

Comment: I swear this used to work, but I wound up here cause it's not working for me either. Annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always change it in the gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.7.1'
```

then run:

```
cd MYAPP
bundle install
```

You can also do it with bundle like [this](https://coderwall.com/p/wrukbg/generate-an-application-with-a-specific-rails-version). Follow this [tutorial](https://www.sharmaprakash.com.np/rails/generate-an-application-with-a-specific-rails-version/) if you'd like more information

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have the rails version you want installed first. If not run this code to install the rails version.

```
gem install rails -v VERSION
```

Then run:

```
rails _4.2.7.1_ new MYAPP
```