# Unable to connect sql server using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems

I am new to ruby on rails and trying to establish a connection to sql server.
I have gone through various articles but still not able to connect to sql server.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.4p296 (2018-03-28 revision 63013) [x64-mingw32]

$ rails -v
Rails 5.2.0
```

After creating a simple rails application, I have changed my database.yml according to the sql settings.

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: sqlserverapp
  username: prakash
  password:
  host: localhost
  database: sqlserverapp
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: sqlserverapp
  username: prakash
  password:
  host: localhost
  database: sqlserverapp
production:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: sqlserverapp
  username: prakash
  password:
  host: localhost
  database: sqlserverapp
```

Tried with both odbc connections normal settings
Errors:

```
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:84:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: undefined method `alias_method_chain' for #<Class:ActiveRecord::Base>
Did you mean?  alias_method
Backtrace for gem load error is:
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter/core_ext/active_record.rb:13:in `singleton class'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter/core_ext/active_record.rb:12:in `included'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter/core_ext/active_record.rb:145:in `include'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter/core_ext/active_record.rb:145:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:71:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:71:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:79:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
C:/Sites/sample/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/sample/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed version `2.3.8` of the `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` gem that is almost 8 years old and tried to run it with the latest version of Ruby on Rails. Obviously, both versions are not compatible.

Furthermore, looking at [the gem's Rubygem page](https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter) - there is no version supporting Ruby on Rails 5.2 yet.

My advice is to downgrade your application to 5.1 and postpone updating to Rails 5.2 until all gems your application is depending on are supporting 5.2

You might want to subscript to these issues on GitHub for further updates:

- https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/issues/636
- https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/issues/647

Comment: Can you please advice on how to degrade to 5.1 version

Comment: Depends on how you got to version 5.2? Is this a new app? Then I would recommend creating a new application with the latest version of Rails 5.1 version (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20968688/2483313 how to do this). Is this an older application that you updated recently? Then you need to revert all changes you made to update to Rails 5.2

Comment: You saved me a lot. Thanks @spickermann for your quick resolution and prompt response.

Comment: Just a note: When you have Rails 5.2 and in your gemfile you specify activerecord-sqlserver-adapter without any specific version, it will install 2.3.8, i suppose it's because it doesn't find a matching compatible version.